# javascript Howto decode file saved as base64 string and download it

Tags: javascript

how must I decode base64 string and download file from base64 string?
Previosly, I encoded a file with:

```
            var strEncoded="";
            file = $('#fileinput1')[0].files[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function () {
                strEncoded = reader.result;
            };
```

Thank you

Comment: @GolezTrol doesn't seem to be PHP involved?

Comment: Not PHP, only javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the b64 version, but instead go directly with the File object you've got from your input.

Up to date browsers do support anchor's `download` attribute, then you just have to do  `a.href = URL.createObjectURL(yourFile); a.download = 'yourfile.whateverExtension'`.

For older browsers, there are a few hacks, all condensed in the great [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/yrezgui/FileSaver.js) library.

Then all you need to do is

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('input');
inp.onchange = function(){
   saveAs(this.files[0], 'yourFile.extension');
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.js"></script>
<input type="file"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `<a>` link and give the data to its `href`. For example i used a data/image base64 like this:

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K........" download>Download</a>
```

`download` attribute would do the work.

Or simply try this:

```
location.href = strEncoded;
```

And in a function:

```
download(dataUrl) {
  location.href = dataUrl;
}

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="download(strEncoded);">Download</a>
```

Comment: It's only run in chrome, not in IE

Comment: @cardonchas i see, IE is always a pain in the azz. I edited my post, can you try javascript version?

Comment: It's run in chrome, but not in IE

Comment: works for image but failed for a pdf file I used application/pdf as mime type of the  base64 encoded data